# Windows 10 login like 7 or XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Is it possible to make login screen of Windows 10 to look like Windows 7. I mean 2 or more user icons (profiles) in center of screen and show password field below icon. Instead of icons in lower left corner and one password field in center.

Current Windows 10 login screen looks like it is optimized for single user of PC.

Comment: “Is it possible to make login screen of Windows 10 to look like Windows 7.” - No; You can list the users on the machine, but it will NOT, look like it did on Windows 7

Comment: Nope. Windows 10 is not Windows 7.

Comment: @John funny you should say that, because "windows 10" is, in essence, windows NT4 with a new desktop environment. Not much has changed "under the hood" only "stylistically" (in quotes because 10 is so -not- styley), so it would surprise me if MS have completely removed the old code and there wasn't a way to get to it.

Comment: @mitts Funny how you're so certain of your assertion. Do you work for Microsoft and are privy with the source code? If not then the one and only honest answer you should ever give is "I don't know". Anything you say beyond that should start with "IMO" because it's nothing more than that.